# Hover на изображениях jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

После наведения мыши на одно изображение ховер эффект воспроизводиться и на всех остальных. Как сделать, чтобы ховер (белый блок с текстом "Project One") отображался только на той картинке, на которую я навел?
Спасибо.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.caption').hide();
});

$(window).load(function(){
    //Блок с описанием
    $('.img, .caption').mouseover(
        function(){
            $(".caption").stop().show(300);
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('.caption').stop().hide(300);
        });

        $(this).addClass(".caption")
    //Мышка на описании

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
              <div class="portfolio-header">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                <p>We understand your requirment and provide quality works</p>
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="thumbs">
                  <img src="imgs/portfolio/row1img1.png"/ class="img">
                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="circle"><span>+</span></div>
                      <span class="title">Project One</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="thumbs">
                  <img src="imgs/portfolio/row1img2.png"/ class="img">
                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="circle"><span>+</span></div>
                      <span class="title">Project One</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="thumbs">
                  <img src="imgs/portfolio/row1img3.png"/ class="img">
                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="circle"><span>+</span></div>
                      <span class="title">Project One</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>        
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: вставьте код текстом, пожалуйста. Неохота перепечатывать с картинки.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/e2cjnspv/2/

```js
$('.caption').hide();

$('.img, .caption').mouseover(
  function(){
    $(this).closest(".thumbs").find(".caption").stop().show(300);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $('.caption').stop().hide(300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
              <div class="portfolio-header">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                <p>We understand your requirment and provide quality works</p>
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="thumbs">
                  <img src="imgs/portfolio/row1img1.png"/ class="img">
                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="circle"><span>+</span></div>
                      <span class="title">Project One</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="thumbs">
                  <img src="imgs/portfolio/row1img2.png"/ class="img">
                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="circle"><span>+</span></div>
                      <span class="title">Project One</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="thumbs">
                  <img src="imgs/portfolio/row1img3.png"/ class="img">
                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="circle"><span>+</span></div>
                      <span class="title">Project One</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>        
        </div>
      </div>
```